# heap setup program in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jvm, jmeter-4.0

Why is the server available memory only about 1.5G, but after setting the HEAP to 5G in jmeter, can it still start normally?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Java Performance Tuning, Profiling, and Memory Management](https://dzone.com/articles/java-performance-tuning) article

> - Unless you have problems with pauses, try granting as much memory as possible to the virtual machine
> - Setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value ….but be sure about the application behaviour
> - Be sure to increase the memory as you increase the number of processors, since allocation can be parallelized
> - Don’t forget to tune the Perm generation

As per [Make Sense of Memory Management and Key Memory Measurements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382715.aspx)

> - **Cached memory** holds data or program code that has been fetched into memory during the current session but is no longer in use now. If necessary, the Windows memory manager will flush the contents of cached memory to make room for newly summoned data.
> - **Free memory** represents RAM that does not contain any data or program code and is free for use immediately.
> - **Commit Charge** (also called commit size) is the total amount of virtual memory that a program has touched (committed) in the current session, including memory that has been paged out of physical memory to the disk-backed page file. The Memory and Physical Memory counters on Task Manager’s Performance tab represent the sum of this value for all processes and the kernel. The Commit Charge Limit is the total amount of physical RAM and page file available—in other words, the maximum virtual memory.

So your system can have much more than you see in `Free memory` as it can allocate additional pages from Cached and Virtual pools therefore it should be OK to provide 5 GB of space to JMeter.

However you need to keep an eye on JVM heap usage and Garbage Collection activity (this can be done using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html)) as if you set too high heap which won't be really used by JMeter the JVM will spend much more time while doing the garbage collection and if there will be page file extensive usage your JMeter engine will not perform well as disk IO is much slower than RAM operations.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more information on tuning JMeter for high loads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, great ! @Dmitri T

Answer (score 1):

What will happen here is that system will swap in/out memory to run Java program.

It might work but willl very negatively impact performances of your Jmeter.

So as a rule of thumb you should absolutely avoid any swap in/out for your java program